# Add field /column to array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

From mysqli request I receive a result that contains a table with 5 columns and a number of rows. I would like to perform a calculation with my data that I just received and add the result of my calc in a NEW COLUMN in my array.
So in different words, I would like to add one column to the array and fill this column with results for each row.

My code so far looks as follows and of course only prints the array that I receive from my SQL query:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
require 'init1.php';

if($result = $db->query("Select * from (select * from(SELECT * FROM `scores` 
ORDER BY `battle_id` ASC,user_id asc,score desc) as t1 GROUP BY 
t1.battle_id, t1.user_id) as t2 order by `battle_id` ASC,score desc")){ 

    if($count = $result->num_rows){
        
        echo '<p>' , $count, '<p>';
        
        while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
            echo $row->battle_id, ' ' , $row->user_id, ' ' , $row->score, '<br>';
        }
        //instead of just printing the existing array, I would like to perform a 
        //calculation and add a result in a new column at the end of every single 
        //row   
    }
}
```

Comment: What calculation are you talking about?

Comment: Well, it is somewhat complex, but just talking about basic math. So for example: any new field in the new column should display the result (score * 2 - 5).

Comment: `echo $row->score * 2 - 5;` Simple, isn't it?

Comment: Not sure which select you need but `Select *, (score * 2 - 5) AS result  ...` then `echo $row->result;`

Comment: Jesus Christ. Embarrassing - but so logical... Thx a lot for the quick response. much appreciated! But can I also have this as a "new array" to continue with this array?

Comment: Sure, just append `$row` to an array (`$rows[] = $row`) after you do that calculation.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an Array you can simply 'define' a new item in your array to store the calculation result.

```
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        // Calculation and other stuff here
        $row['calc_result'] = $calculation_result;
    }
```

Then in order to access it outside the while scope, you would need to store each row in another array, for example:

```
$stored_data = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    // Calculation and other stuff here
    $row['calc_result'] = $calculation_result;
    array_push( $stored_data, $row );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I meant to use an array and forgot to change $result->fetch_object to $result->fetch_row . Fixed it. :)

Comment: Thx again, I have now the following: